# Get a list of all the elements between two tag

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

```
I have webpage similar to this
        <h2> ... </h2>
        <h3> ... </h3>
        <p> ... </p>
        <p> ... </p>
        <h2> ... </h2>
        <h3> ... </h3>
        <p> ... </p>
        <h2> ... </h2>
        <h3> ... </h3>
        <p> ... <p>
```

How could I find elements between first h2 and last h2 tag in c# using
selenium. Also I want all elements below last h2 tag as well. Thanks

Comment: What exactly the output should look like ?. You can use find_elements() method to return the list of elements.

Comment: @Sureshmani Thanks for you reply!! I want output in a way so that I can get the tag value and tag name as well of elements.